# Quick preview of folders for fast inspection

Tags: nautilus, files, directory, fsck

i have to inspect something like 500+ folders after a fsck recover. Is there a tool or a cli shortcut to quick preview the content of a folder and, if the files are from a certain type (pdf and mp3 in my case) mark the folder and move it to somewhere else? In windogs, folder views can be customized to show a "hint" of what you can find inside (it's blank when the folder is empty).

Answer (score 0):

The command "file" reveals the nature of a file. It could be used in a little script that moves files to subfolders based on the file type. It features the option `-b`, making it output just the file type, which is convenient for use in a script.

For visual inspection of the classified files, a tool like `sushi` can come in handy. It is a preview tool. The window can remain open and will update to display the file highlighted in nautilus file manager. This applies if you use the standard Ubuntu desktop. Other desktop environments may have different tools.